# Extracting duplicate data from a .csv into another .csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I have a .csv file with multiple duplicate data entries.

Example of entries when viewed in notepad:

```
"Tom    1234"
"Andrew    4321"
```

I would like to extract the duplicate entries into another .csv along with line numbers. An expected output would look something like this.

[image]

Using

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample_dup.csv')
df[df.duplicated(subset=None, keep=False)].to_csv('dups.csv')
```

I managed to export this,

[image]

But my expected result is supposed to be this,

[image]

This is the data file in question

[image]

What went wrong for the first entry to keep appearing at the top of the list? and why is the numbering incorrect as well?

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [pd.Duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)-

```
df[df.duplicated()].to_csv('dups.csv')
```

If you want a subset, use the `subset` parameter...